# "Too Many Arguments" error in IF function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was trying to formulate an automated indicator for the lot size of commodities, so I drafted this `IF` function but it gives an error saying "too many arguments". How can I overcome this hindrance?

```
=IF(E2="GOLD",100,IF(E2="GOLDM",10,IF(E2="SILVER",30,IF(E2="SILVERM",5,IF("CRUDEOIL",100,IF(E2="COPPER",1000,IF="COPPERM",250,IF(E2="NATURALGAS",1250,0)))))))
```

Comment: From memory, Excel's IF function can only be nested 6 deep. You should investigate the VLOOKUP function.

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick Nope. I don't know what the limit is but it's at least 8.

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick Just checked and it works nested for at least 42 deep ;-)

Comment: Only few corrections,, you have missed to include cell address E2 with CRUDEOIL & COPPERM,, check @robinCTS formul, will work for you.

Comment: Obligatory hint: Don’t try to solve everything with Excel. Take a step back and think about this again. It looks terrible and it’s not maintainable.

Comment: As an alternative you van use Lookup formula also to solve this,, if yo feel I can suggest you how to do it !!

Comment: Maybe, a different approach should also be tried: if using Excel 2016, the SWITCH function might come in handy and dispense us from the parentheses hassle. I'd try something like: `=SWITCH(E2,"GOLD",100,"GOLDM",10,"SILVER",30,"SILVERM",5,"CRUDEOIL",100,"COPPER",1000,"COPPERM",250,"NATURALGAS",1250,0)`

Comment: @DroidW Not everybody has Excel 2016, though ;-) However, that would be the best way to do it. Apart from putting the data in a table and using `VLOOKUP()` (or `INDEX()`/`MATCH()`.), of course.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT also is a good choose, but you need provide a sample of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `(E2` in the `COPPERM` part (which then requires an extra closing `)`). That's what's causing the error.

The `CRUDEOIL` part is also missing the check against `E2`, which I have fixed:

```dart
=IF(E2="GOLD",100,IF(E2="GOLDM",10,IF(E2="SILVER",30,IF(E2="SILVERM",5,IF(E2="CRUDEOIL",100,IF(E2="COPPER",1000,IF(E2="COPPERM",250,IF(E2="NATURALGAS",1250,0))))))))
```

---

As recommended by a few users, here's a simple example of how to use `VLOOKUP()` to do the same thing as your formula:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]